# CAAnimation on a UIButton

Tags: xcode, uibutton, caanimation

I have been trying to create a simple swipe transition. However buttons seem immune to any CAAnimation that crops.

I am trying to get it so that a bar moves across the screen and as it goes over the button it removes the part it has just gone over.

I have tried bounds.width, size.x and many other key-value paths to achieve the affect but I haven't got what I wanted. It just relocates the text which always remains entirely visible
I have also tried changing the UIButton to a UIImage but the text does not seem to print on a UIImage.
I tried using masks too but I have heard they should be used as infrequently as possible as they consume the phones resources. I didn't really get very far with this either anyway as I hadn't used them much before.
I also tried placing it in a container view and then change the dimensions of that but again all of the text remained entirely visible.

I know I could have a view hide the button but I am trying to reveal the view behind as the bar swipes.

Does anyone have any suggestions of how to achieve a swipe transition on a UIButton?

Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is the code you are trying to run ?

Comment: The problem is not that the code isn't working. The problem is that I don't know what code to write to achieve the effect I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for really is a mask. See the tutorial here:
http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-mask-an-image.html

What I'd do in your situation is create a custom UIButton class, and add a mask as in the tutorial, then animate the position of the mask. Slide the mask of, nothing shows. Slide it on, part shows until the whole thing is visible.

Edit: I haven't really heard anything about hogging resources, especially since it appears to be simple core graphics.

Comment: Thanks XenElement. I tried using masks before. However, in the tutorial you suggest it masks an image. I can't make the UIButton an image as the text seems to disappear as soon as I have changed it. Do you know of a way to change a UIButton to a UIImage and it retain the text? Cheers

Comment: What do you mean by retaining the text? Keeping the title of the button visible?

Comment: Yes for some reason the button title is no longer visible when I change it in to a UIImage. If you have a way of doing this I would really appreciate it. If I was changing it to a UIImage (and the text remains visible) then can I not just animate the bounds and create the effect I want? Thanks for the help.

Comment: In theory, you could add a UILabel on top of the button to show the title separately. Then animate the button behind it however you wish. Note: make sure to say userInteractionEnabled = FALSE on the label.

Comment: Using a mask works well and you don't need to convert the UIButton to a UIImage. It is hard to tell what is going on with your masks though, which is where I went wrong previously, so I recommend changing background colours to help.